# Creating a filter of content types?

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type called college facilities. This displays ALL the college facilities that are added. I would like to create more content types called:

- Services
- Food
- College Supplies
- Other

I was wondering is it possible to create a drop down filter on the college facilities page so that if a user select all then all of them are displayed or Food then only food content types are displayed?

[image]

This is what I would like it to look like with ALL being pre selected. 
Is this possible? 
I apologize I am very new to drupal and Im using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to create Views page where you add exposed filter on the content types.

This is how you create an exposed filter
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Yk6rre3vi8

If that is unclear for you, I will make a screenshot.

Regards,

Oleg